# CSS - Crear un "div" responsive

Tags: css

Intento crear un div responsive, el cual en dispositivos como laptops tenga la altura total 100vh, pero al pasar a dispositivos móviles se adapte a la altura ocupada por el contenido.

De momento no se adapta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo sale de flujo.

Los estilos son los siguientes.

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Container = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background: #141432;
`  

const SubContainer = styled.div`
    width: 90%;
    height: calc(100% - 6.25em);
    max-height: 695px;
 

    max-width: 1600px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
`

export {Container, SubContainer}
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Para tu caso considero que lo ideal sería comenzar con los `viewports`, de modo que desde el principio ya tengas tu contenedor principal adaptable a cualquier tamaño de pantalla.

El siguiente paso sería adaptar en esa ventana reposive todos los elementos que quieras agregar en ella.

Para configurar la ventana gráfica, HTML5 introdujo un método que permite tomar el control de la ventana gráfica a través de la etiqueta `<meta>` en todas tus páginas web:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

> Esto le da al navegador instrucciones sobre cómo controlar las
> dimensiones y la escala de la página.
>
> El `width=device-width` establece el ancho de la página para seguir
> el ancho de pantalla del dispositivo (que variará según el
> dispositivo).
>
> La parte `initial-scale=1.0` establece el nivel de zoom inicial > cuando el navegador carga la página por primera vez.

Después de configurar tu `viewport` la ventana principal se adaptará a los dispositivos y en ella podrás adaptar tus elementos a esa ventana adaptable.

Toda la informacion al respecto la podras encontrar en este articulo [viewports](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Otra cosa que te puede ayudar muchísimo sería el uso de una biblioteca como [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), su documentación es realmente fácil y de manera sencilla ofrece exactamente lo que estás buscando. Obviamente hay una pequeña configuración previa, pero es realmente fácil hacer uso de todas sus cualidades. Vale la MUCHO pena intentarlo.